# Android gesture detection for English alphabets

Tags: java, android, uigesturerecognizer, gesture-recognition

I am developing an application in which English alphabet will be written in gestures format and those alphabets will be written in the text view, but my problem is my app is not detecting the gestures correctly even I have different gestures for the same word. or is there any other way to make the gesture detection accurate? Please help!